# Rhinomock non-primitive object in expectations

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, rhino-mocks

it seems comments can't support code

Lets say I call a method (e.g. SaveTicket) and have used constructor(e.g. Repository, Logging) to inject various mock interfaces. If that method calls another object and creates a non-primitive object inside that method. Is there any easy way to test the values of that non-primitive object?

I guess trying to replace that non-primitive object with property and injecting is possible, or Using LastCall.Constraints. Is there a better way?

Here is an example - in the below example - in order to verify 
   Repository.save(t);

is called with correct values of t I can

1. Do lastcall.constraints
2. lastcall.ignorearguments

Is there a better way?

```
CreateMyTicket(int ticketnumber, string name)
{
   ticketobject t = new ticketObject(ticketnumber, name);
   t.upgrade = ticketnumber+2;
   Repository.save(t);
}
```

Comment: Could you show some code please? The classes and interfaces involved.

Comment: You lost me. Which method is the method you test? Where does this "other object" come from? Is it created by the unit under test or by the mock?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's take an example. Suppose that you have the following class and you want to unit test the `CreateMyTicket` method:

```
public class ClassToTest
{
    public IRepository Repository { get; private set; }

    public ClassToTest(IRepository repository)
    {
        Repository = repository;
    }

    public void CreateMyTicket(int ticketnumber, string name)
    {
        var t = new TicketObject(ticketnumber, name);
        t.Upgrade = ticketnumber + 2;
        Repository.Save(t);
    }
}
```

This assumes that we have an `IRepository` interface:

```
public interface IRepository
{
    void Save(TicketObject t);
}
```

and here's how a sample unit test could look like:

```
[TestMethod]
public void CreateMyTicketTest() 
{
    // arrange
    var repositoryStub = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IRepository>();
    var sut = new ClassToTest(repositoryStub);
    var ticketNumber = 5;
    var name = "John";

    // act
    sut.CreateMyTicket(ticketNumber, name);

    // assert
    repositoryStub.AssertWasCalled(
        x => x.Save(
            Arg<TicketObject>.Matches(t => 
                t.Upgrade == 7 && 
                t.Name == name && 
                t.TicketNumber == ticketNumber
            )
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: Yep, This answers it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should only test which methods was called on mocked dependencies (Repository, Logging). Verifying objects, returned from mocks, give you nothing (because you verify what you just created manually and set as return result).